# Django multiple app connect to multiple DB(sqlite)

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have two Django apps,
each with one models.py.
I'd like to connect the db to each app,
what should I do?

The first app is notice. If only notice connects to db, it will work normally.

```py
#/notice/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model

class Notice(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

This is the second app, rc_db. If I connect rc_db, the lowest error occurs.

```py
#/rc_db/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model

# Create your models here.
class rc_db(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

```py
#/config/settings/base.py

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'info',
    'rcdb',
    'notice.apps.NoticeConfig',
    'rc_db.apps.RcDbConfig',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
}
```

And an error like this occurs.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: rc_db
```

Comment: What did you do ? Show us some code first so we can help you out on **existing** snippet of code

Comment: Indeed, it would be easier to help you if you get us at least some model from your models.py. Also, provide us database config in your settings.py

Comment: I came home late, so I'm uploading it now.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted rcdb from base.py and it works normally.

```py
#/config/settings/base.py

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'info',
    'notice.apps.NoticeConfig',
    'rc_db.apps.RcDbConfig',
]
```